# Change values of NSArray after init

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

For my homework I have to write the .h and .m to a Command-line application, the main is given by my teacher. It a simple Chutes and Ladders style board print-out of 100 spaces.

The Ladders and Chutes will be indicated by "L10", and "C10" inside of a single dimension array that stores the board's representation. The first part of the given main is the initBoard which I think I will have create an empty string array. The number of Ladders and Chutes are given in the next two lines of the supplied code, and I am suppose to populate the board with them randomly via their methods.

**If I use a for loop in a "initBoard"**(the first thing the main calls)**method to build a NSArray to a size of 100, populating it with empty stings, will I be able to change the empty strings into the "L10" and "C10" strings that I want in my "makeLadders" and "makeChutes" methods, or do I have to use an NSMutableArray for something like this?**

I have read that NSArray is immutable, meaning that it cannot be modified after init, so one must use NSMutableArray if one wishes to modify the contents of arrays. My teacher specifically mentions NSArrays as what should hold the board data so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices here:

1. A mutable array containing NSString objects;
2. An immutable array containing NSMutableString objects.

Example with the first choice:

```
NSMutableArray* array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 100];
for(NSUInteger i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    [array addObject: @""];
}
```

To change the values use:

```
[array replaceObjectAtIndex: i withObject: @"New String"];
```

Comment: Ooh, the objects contained within the immutable array can be changed! IDK why that didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Except that `-[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]` doesn't change an existing entry in the array, it inserts a new one. Try [`-[NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:) instead. Assuming you're targeting iOS 5 or 10.6 or later, you can use the `array[i] = newObject;` syntax too.